# Results of calculating with sum of AVERAGE (expression) give a wrong number in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a column which was calculated *"How many employees work in each departments"* and i used this expr **=Avg(Fields!TotalEmployees.Value)** to know how many employees work or worked in departments.
 and then i used this expr **=Sum(AVG(Fields!TotalEmployees.Value))** for calculate total of sum from results of avg.
 and than, when i didn't choose between 2 different dates on top - calculate of SUM of AVG is correct as you can see in screenshots :
 [image: w]

BUT , when i choose between 2 different dates on top - calculate of SUM of AVG is not correct and it gives wrong number as you can see in screenshots : 
[image: y]
Body of report look like this : 
[image: r]

Can someone please point me in the right direction? or in ssrs ,do we have ! something like , if i did not choose between 2 dates do not calculating Sum of Avg else calculating Sum of Avg or something solved this issue !

Comment: @AlanSchofield , i also tried with Sum of Avg ,but its gives wrong number again

Answer (score 0):

Can't you specify a default value for parameters and not change your query?

Comment: tnx for your comment , other ways i have to change something in my query for calculating